# Shortcut to copy current cursor coordinates in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, coordinates

Is there a shortcut or an extension to ArcMap 10 that would allow me to quickly copy (to clipboard) the coordinates at the current map position/click?

I could implement such a functionality easily enough.  However, I'm hoping someone has already done so.

---

Apparently the code is much simpler than I figured:

```
IPoint pt = ArcMap.Document.CurrentLocation;
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, pt.X + " " + pt.Y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Implementing mouse down event when user clicks on map using ArcObjects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4630) shows you how to get xy coordinate values.

You can then assign the x and y values to the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks @artwork21, I implemented it as a custom button this morning and added a keyboard shortcut to it.  I'll post the code.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify whether you just wanted to do this through the ArcMap GUI.  If that is the case just use the Identify tool to point at a location.  As well as returning features found you will see a Location bar which can be copy/pasted from.

Comment: My goal was to hover over any location on the map and with a single key press copy the current map coordinates.  I'm aware of identify + copy coordinates, but that's too many steps.  Thanks for the answer though, may help someone else in the future.