# Mouse Double Click Events

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#, tools, events

I would like to display a Message Box Dialog when the user activates the -esri selection tool- and double clicks anywhere on the map. or when they doubleclick any feature on the map

please note that I am not creating a new tool. MapControl is an option but I am not able to access the object, or cast anything to it. so please help

EDIT:-
I have tried to cast my Focus map into a Mapcontrol and get that object and cast into ImapControlEvents2. and threw it I can handle the OndoubleClick event

I have tried getting the selection tool from the active tool and caste it into an Itool object but that didnt work since I am not creating a new tool,

I researched the API Reference provided on esri website to see what options I have and I found nothing that might help me. the interfaces that I need are the following,

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you **edit** your question and add more information?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: It has been a while since I have dealt in ArcObjects, but looking at (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4630/how-to-implement-mouse-down-event-when-the-user-clicks-on-the-map) leads me to believe you can override the doubleclick event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx) and hopefully you can capture the mouse point area and convert it to map units using one of the ArcObjects interfaces.

Comment: here is what I did, I created a class that implements basetool, implemented all of base tool's methods. I run VS, arcmap opens, click on the map nothing happens. note that I am not trying to create a new tool, I am simply trying to catch the mouse events from the esri selction tool which is not working. Any other solutions or ideas ?

Comment: I have come to conclusion that it is not possible, unless I create a new tool .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new tool in order to implement mouse events!

Comment: can expand on this to make it a better answer (even though it is an accepted answer) like how to implement mouse events